# How can I group rows in SQL and sum them up?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table like this in SQL Server 2017, let's call it "maps_and_cups"

| some_code | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| big_map | 6 |
| tiny_map | 5 |
| big_cup | 10 |
| tiny_cup | 4 |

I would like to know the best way to group the maps and cups into one, in this way.

| some_code | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| maps | 11 |
| cups | 14 |

I know that it is using "if" and "case", adding and comparing if it is a tiny_map, a big_map, and so on, I have seen several examples but I cannot make it compile.

Comment: Can you search for underscores and extract the text that follows to get the common grouping?

Comment: In fact, I'd rather evaluate word for word, suppose big_map, tiny_map, big_cup and tiny_cup are static, and must be explicitly named in the query

Comment: `group by case when some_code in ('big_map', 'tiny_map') then 'maps' when some_code in (' big_cup', 'tiny_cup') then 'cups' end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a `case when` expression. For instance:

```
with base as
(select case some_code when 'big_map' then 'maps' 
                       when 'tiny_map' then 'maps' 
                       when 'big_cup' then 'cups' 
                       when 'tiny_cup' then 'cups'
              else 'other'
         end grp, 
         quantity
from maps_and_cups)
select grp, sum(quantity) quantity from base group by grp;
```

However, if you're going to list each and every code explicitly, you might as well create a reference table for it:

| some_code | grp |
| --- | --- |
| big_map | maps |
| tiny_map | maps |
| big_cup | cups |
| tiny_cup | cups |

...and then join that table into your query:

```
select grp, sum(quantity) 
from maps_and_cups a left join ref_maps_cups b on a.some_code = b.some_code
group by grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this task using "case" and "charindex" functions, like this:

```
declare
    @t table (some_code varchar (20), quantity int)

insert into @t
values
('big_map', 6),
('tiny_map', 5),
('big_cup',10),
('tiny_cup', 4)

select 
    case
        when charindex ('map', some_code)>0 then 'map'
        when charindex ('cup', some_code)>0 then 'cup'
    end some_code
    ,sum(quantity) quantity
from @t
group by 
    case
        when charindex ('map', some_code)>0 then 'map'
        when charindex ('cup', some_code)>0 then 'cup'
    end
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the right three characters for aggregating, you can use `right()`:

```
select right(some_code, 3) + 's', sum(quantity)
from maps_and_cups
group by right(some_code, 3) + 's';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a problem for yourself as you're (probably) breaking the first normal form by storing non atomic values in the field "some_code". (Some field name i'd say. ;)

Why not separating the value into [ type ] and [ size ] ?

Comment: Because I am working with an existing table where things were done this way. And at the moment I can't add columns